# Laptop making short beep after using it for more than 40 minutes

Tags: hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo laptop and recently I opened it up to clean the dust. After that, it is acting weird like after using it for 40-45 minutes, it makes a short beep sound.

I tried running 'chk dsk' to scan the hard drive but I think everything is okay with the hard drive.
I also used core temp to monitor the heating status and it looks fine. (48)

So can anyone help me to identify the problem with my laptop? Yes, it once also caused BSOD before the hard drive scan, but now it is working fine at the moment.

Comment: Are all ventilators still turning freely?

Comment: Yes, i can hear the fan running and I have checked the airflow as well.

Comment: there's only one?

Comment: One beep and multiple clicking sounds

Comment: I meant the fans.  But I see your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Lenovo Support site for your geographic area. Download, install and run the Lenovo Diagnostics app. Run it for all hardware items. See if it says there is a hardware issue.

Go to:  https://www.memtest86.com/  , make a bootable USB Key for memtest86.exe, boot with this key and test memory. Run two or three passes.

From the above, determine if the beeping is hardware (likely) or somehow software.

If software, you will need to consider a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: Hi, I got 'bad sectors found' when ran tests on the hard drive. What to do now?

Comment: So I have answered your question, and now you need to replace the drive. Back up immediately, and contact Lenovo for a replacement drive.

Comment: Could it be just a loose wire because the hard drive was working fine before I opened up my laptop?

Comment: If you can open the Laptop, reseat the hard drive and look for loose wires. But I find Lenovo Diagnostics to be pretty good. It was able to read the drive and found bad sectors.